# finding size of pointer to array

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>



#define R 10

#define C 20



int main()

{

   int (*p)[R][C];

   printf("%d",  sizeof(*p));

   getchar();

   return 0;

}
```

o/p= 800

here p is a pointer to a 2-D array .. so shouldn't its o/p be 4 or 8?

Comment: You're printing the size of the 2D array (R=10, C=20, `int`s have a size of 4, so 10*20*4=800), not the size of the pointer. Just do sizeof `p`.

Comment: You're using the wrong format for `sizeof`. See e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for a nice table about the different formats and *modifiers* for different types.

Comment: `sizeof p` means the size of p. `sizeof *p` means the size of what p points to.

Comment: Would one of you (maybe @AntonH, with highest ticks) like to turn the comments into an answer? The three comments combined seem like a very detailed and useful answer to a passable question, at least no downvotes. I like to keep the list of "unanswered" questions short.

Comment: @Yunnosch I added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you're not displaying the size of the pointer, but the size of the memory chunk that the pointer is pointing to.

R=10, and C=20. `int`s have a size of 4 bytes on your system. So 10*20*4=800. So with your code, `printf("%d",  sizeof(*p));` will print **800**.

If you're looking to print the size of the pointer variable, you would have to change your code to this:

```
printf("%d",  sizeof(p));
```

Reference: [printf reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) courtesy of [some-programmer-dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)

Comment: Thank You , Sir :)

Comment: @chux I saw https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat with duplicates [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136833/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-user-to-accept-my-answer). I didn't ask to upvote answer, just to accept it.

Comment: @PawanKumar Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)